# PHP add missing key in loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array.

```
    [rows] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2704783858001796
                        [rowNumber] => 1
                        [expanded] => 1
                        [createdAt] => 2020-02-18T18:42:54Z
                        [modifiedAt] => 2020-02-18T22:07:36Z
                        [cells] => Array
                            (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [columnId] => 1676391784703876
                                            [value] => Approved
                                            [displayValue] => Approved
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [columnId] => 1225963934640004
                                            [value] => Submitted
                                            [displayValue] => Submitted
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [columnId] => 4979307467564932
                                            [value] => 2020-02-18
                                        )
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [columnId] => 3203730339325828
```

Where [value] and [displayValue] are not always shown.  When I loop through the array, I need to be able to insert a [value] as blank or 0.  I cannot have the loop skip over the key.

```
$j = count($dataID['rows']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
    array_push($dataRows, array_column($dataID['rows'][$i]['cells'], 'value'));
}
```

Comment: No clue what you want with `array_push` here, or what that `$dataRows` is even supposed to be. You need a second loop here, to go over all the `cells` in each one of your row items - and then insert those properties on that level, if they are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code loops through every element of `$dataID['row']` and within through every element of `$row['cells']` to add the both keys if they dont exists:

```
foreach( $dataID['rows'] as &$row ) {
  foreach( $row['cells'] as &$cell ) {
    if( !array_key_exists( 'value', $cell ) )  {
      $cell['value'] = null;
    }
    if( !array_key_exists( 'displayValue', $cell ) )  {
      $cell['displayValue'] = null;
    }
  }
}
```

So that this array `(short version of yours)`:

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cells] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Becomes:

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cells] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 
                                    [displayValue] => 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 
                                    [displayValue] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow :-)

In this case `array_column` is skipping if the column does not exist. I would add a user-function where you can control your default values and use `array_map` instead.

Your custom function:

```
function array_column_with_default(array $array, string $key, $default = null)
{
    return array_map(function ($item) use ($key, $default) {
        if (false === array_key_exists($key, $item)) {
            return $default;
        }
        return $item[$key];
    }, $array);
}
```

And here is your code-example with `array_map()` instead of `array_column`:

```
$j = count($dataID['rows']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
    array_push($dataRows, array_column_with_default($rows[$i]['cells'], 'value', ''));
}
```

Below you'll see a test dataset and example output

```
$rows = [
    [
        // ... other attributes
        'cells' => [
            ['value' => 'Approved'],
            ['value' => 'Submitted'],
            ['value' => '2020-02-18'],
        ],
    ],
    [
        // ... other attributes
        'cells' => [
            ['value' => 'Not Approved'],
            ['value' => 'Not Submitted'],
            [], // i.e. no date given
        ],
    ],
];
```

will output the following

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "Approved"
    [1] =>
    string(9) "Submitted"
    [2] =>
    string(10) "2020-02-18"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(12) "Not Approved"
    [1] =>
    string(13) "Not Submitted"
    [2] =>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I never recommend trying to modify a data structure while you are walking through it.  Instead, "walk through it, building some kind of list of the changes you need to make."  Then, after the walk is finished, go back and apply the changes.

Alternatively, each time you make a change, *restart* the walk.